# Direction aware neighborhood

Tags: cytoscape.js

Are there ways to get neighborhoods of node but direction aware?

For example, I have nodes:

```
[
    { 'id': 'a' },
    { 'id': 'b' },
    { 'id': 'c' }
]
```

and edges:

```
[
    { 'id': 'ab', 'source': 'a', 'destination': 'b' },
    { 'id': 'ac', 'source': 'a', 'destination': 'c' },
]
```

And now, when I call `nodeB.neighborhoods()` I have a `nodeA` as result.
But `nodeB` is not connected to `nodeA` (only `nodeA` connected to `nodeB`).

Maybe `cytoscape.js` already has function, that I can use for get all connected nodes to specific node?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a selector query on the edges, which have a source and target property

> Please note that this snippet doesn't have console.log() for a reason:
>
> The collection cytoscape returns is a pretty large array of information, so the stackoverflow console is not capable to show that, it tries to show it as a formatted string or something and then freezes on the sheer amount of lines it has to process...

```js
var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById('cy'),

  boxSelectionEnabled: false,
  autounselectify: true,

  style: [{
      selector: 'node',
      css: {
        'content': 'data(id)',
        'text-valign': 'center',
        'text-halign': 'center',
        'height': '60px',
        'width': '60px',
        'border-color': 'black',
        'border-opacity': '1',
        'border-width': '10px'
      }
    },
    {
      selector: 'edge',
      css: {
        'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle'
      }
    }
  ],

  elements: {
    nodes: [{
        data: {
          id: 'a'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'b'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'c'
        }
      }
    ],
    edges: [{
        data: {
          source: 'a',
          target: 'b'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: 'a',
          target: 'c'
        }
      }
    ]
  },

  layout: {
    name: 'concentric'
  }
});

// First option: getting the edges with the sourceId "a" and then all targtes of these edges
var targets = cy.edges('[source = "a"]').targets();

// Second option: getting the node with the id "#a" and then this nodes outgoers (all outgoing edges and their target node). After that, you can either get all edges with .edges() or all nodes with .nodes()
var alternative = cy.$('#a').outgoers().nodes();
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

#cy {
  height: 100%;
  width: 75%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.2.17/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.3.1/dist/jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>

</html>
```